# adS click in Webview

Tags: webview

already I convert the website into an app. I will make sure to include all the necessary permissions such as accessing contacts, WhatsApp, Facebook, and more. However, the only issue I have encountered is that when a user clicks on ads within the WebView, it redirects them to the web browser instead of opening within the WebView itself. This means that it opens in the Chrome custom tab using an Intent.

already I convert the website into an app. I will make sure to include all the necessary permissions such as accessing contacts, WhatsApp, Facebook, and more. However, the only issue I have encountered is that when a user clicks on ads within the WebView, it redirects them to the web browser instead of opening within the WebView itself. This means that it opens in the Chrome custom tab using an Intent